# Checking image size logic using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I made the function which is for checking images' size before submit. It works without error but i found the exception that the images are allowed to upload if it contains only one image is correct size. This happen occurs because of the incorrect boolean. I know how can I detect this in dirty way 
I know my code is dumb but could you guys check my code?

```
function check_scr_img_size() {
var img_size;
var ss = $('.tmp_screenshot').length;
console.log("업로드할 스크린샷 갯수 : "+  ss);

var scr = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < ss ; i ++) {
    console.log("check_scr_img_size");
    scr[i] = document.getElementById('tmp_scr'+i);
    console.log(scr[i].naturalWidth + " , " + scr[i].naturalHeight);

    if(scr[i].naturalWidth == 1440 && scr[i].naturalHeight == 810) {
        img_size = true;
    }else {
        img_size = false;
    }
}

if (img_size) {
    console.log("check_scr_img_size : true");
    return true;
}else {
    console.log("check_scr_img_size : false");
    if (lang == "ko") {
        popup("스크린샷 이미지를 확인해 주세요. (사이즈 : 1440 X 810");
    }else {
        popup("Please check your screenshots images (size : 1440 X 810");
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

How can I fix this? Please let me know the way that I can modify my code more clean and optimized.

---

I tried it and the log is like this.

`스크린샷 존재
업로드할 스크린샷 존재 
업로드할 스크린샷 갯수 : 2 // The 2files have to be uploaded.
check_scr_img_size
518, 346 // The first image size
check_scr_img_size
1440, 810 // The second image size
check_scr_img_size : true // It turns to true 
스크린샷 존재 && 업로드할 스크린샷 존재 && 업로드할 스크린샷 사이즈 일치`

The bool is just changed if the last image is true.

I changed the code like this that you said.

```
function check_scr_img_size() {
var img_size=true;
var ss = $('.tmp_screenshot').length;
console.log("업로드할 스크린샷 갯수 : "+  ss);

var scr = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < ss ; i ++) {
    console.log("check_scr_img_size ");
    scr[i] = document.getElementById('tmp_scr'+i);
    console.log(scr[i].naturalWidth + " , " + scr[i].naturalHeight);

     if(!scr[i].naturalWidth == 1440 && !scr[i].naturalHeight == 810) {
         //img_size = true;
     //}else {
         img_size = false;
     }
 }

if (img_size) {
    console.log("check_scr_img_size : true");
    return true;
}else {
    console.log("check_scr_img_size : false");
    if (lang == "ko") {
        popup("스크린샷 이미지를 확인해 주세요. (사이즈 : 1440 X 810");
    }else {
        popup("Please check your screenshots images (size : 1440 X 810");
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

---

Thank you it works properly. I changed the`(!scr[i].naturaWidth == 1440 && !scr[i].naturalHeight == 810)` to `scr[i].naturalWidth != 1440 && scr[i].naturalHeight != 810` and i also added the `break;` after `img_size = false;`. I'm really appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove setting `img_size` to `true`. Instead init `img_size` with `true`:

```
var img_size = true;
// in your loop:
// ...
if(scr[i].naturalWidth != 1440 && scr[i].naturalHeight != 810) {
    img_size = false;
}
```

So you will always get `false` if some bad image received.

Comment: I applied your code and it did work in wrong way. Could you check my question again? I updated my question. Thanks

Comment: @홍의숙 wow actually `(!scr[i].naturaWidth == 1440 && !scr[i].naturalHeight == 810)` will always return false, it means `if( false==1440 && false==810)` we all missed it and I don't know why u_mulder made this... it should be  `if(scr[i].naturalWidth !== 1440 || scr[i].naturalHeight !== 810)`

Comment: Yeah my mistake. Updated. Thanks @Kaiido

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
function check_scr_img_size() {
    var img_size = true,
        ss = $('.tmp_screenshot').length,
        scr = [];
    console.log("업로드할 스크린샷 갯수 : " + ss);
    for (var i = 0; i < ss; i++) {
        if (img_size === true) {
            console.log("check_scr_img_size");
            scr[i] = document.getElementById('tmp_scr' + i);
            console.log(scr[i].naturalWidth + " , " + scr[i].naturalHeight);
            if (scr[i].naturalWidth != 1440 || scr[i].naturalHeight != 810) {
                img_size = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (img_size) {
        console.log("check_scr_img_size : true");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("check_scr_img_size : false");
        if (lang == "ko") {
            popup("스크린샷 이미지를 확인해 주세요. (사이즈 : 1440 X 810");
        } else {
            popup("Please check your screenshots images (size : 1440 X 810");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's indeed a good way, but instead of checking if `img_size` is true in the for loop, you could `break;` it if it is false.

Comment: It is true. And I think it would be faster with one iteration and one assignment.

Comment: @홍의숙 This is another way of doing it, similar to the one of u_mulder.